# RedirectFromLoginPage issue across directories

Tags: c#, asp.net, redirect

I seem to be facing a rather odd issue with RedirectFromLoginPage and pages across folders.

I've a website with "Forms" authentication enabled, with the Login page in the Forms folder and other aspx pages in the Reports folder.
So to get to a report you would go - http://Servername/Reports/Report1.aspx and if you're not logged in, you'll be redirected to the Login page - 
http://Servername/Forms/Login.aspx?ReturnUrl=../Reports/Report1.aspx, which seems right.

In my aspx code on the login page, once I check the Login info and create the Authcookie I then check if I've a ReturnUrl and if I do, I use 
`System.Web.Security.FormsAuthentication.RedirectFromLoginPage(username, false);` for redirection.

Note the redirected url for the Login page - 
http://Servername/Forms/Login.aspx?ReturnUrl=../Reports/Report1.aspx
seems right in principle, but on logging in the redirect never happens, I'm not even sure what is going on, it just sits there and then comes up with a "No Data received" in Chrome - net::ERR_EMPTY_RESPONSE.

However, if I try with http://Servername/Forms/Login.aspx?ReturnUrl=/Reports/Report1.aspx, the redirect happens as expected, note the difference being
`ReturnUrl=/Reports/Report1.aspx` that works versus
`ReturnUrl=../Reports/Report1.aspx` which does not, though the former is incorrect and the latter is correct from a folder standpoint.

Am I missing something very trivial (is the redirect not happening from the context of the Login page?), I can step in and correct the issue by removing the leading ".." or else use Respsone.Redirect (which works with the `../Reports/Report1.aspx`), but I would expect the framework to do proper redirection since the rest of the stuff is being handled by Forms Authentication.

EDIT 1  - I've checked IIS logs, and I see no mention of the Redirects for the `../Reports/Report1.aspx` scenario, which makes sense since the redirects never happen.

Comment: that means you have to remove the two dots to make it work.

Comment: I know! But I did not place those dots, the .Net framework did so and it is right in placing those dots going by the folder structure.

Comment: that is interesting. I am curious to know what server response look like ( especially Location header ) when you use Server.Redirect( with the ../Reports/Report1.aspx)

Comment: Sorry yantaq - I was doing stupid stuff.

Answer (score 0):

Apologies - I guess this is why one needs to be aware of the code one writes!
I feel stupid now, it was not the .Net Framework that was creating the ReturnUrl string, I was doing it and I removed the extra periods on there.

Sorry again.